Unable to get length of arg - C
basically I'm trying to get the length (using strlen) of an argument, but i keep getting this error. From what I've understood it means that I'm giving an array of pointers to char arrays instead of a pointer to a char array, but I don't understand why since argv[i], where 0 < i < argc, should be a "string". Here's the code and the error.
Code :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv[]){
        if (argc != 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "INVALID NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS");
                return 1;
        }
        else {
                printf("%d", strlen(argv[1]));
        }
        return 0;
}

Error :
arg.c: In function ‘main’:
arg.c:10:41: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   10 |                 printf("%d", strlen(argv[1]));
      |                                     ~~~~^~~
      |                                         |
      |                                         char **
In file included from arg.c:2:
/usr/include/string.h:407:35: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
  407 | extern size_t strlen (const char *__s)
      |                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~


Also tried just reading argv[1] as a string (printf("%s", argv[1]);) and it worked.

argv should be declared as char *argv[] or char **argv.

You're passing a triple pointer in main(). The correct type is char *[] (or char **), not char **[]. Decaying char **[] will result into char***.
Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function
